# Cast Object to class from passed params

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have a code:

RequestHandler.java

```
public class RequestHandler extends BaseWebSocketRequestHandler {
 ...
 public void handle(Request request)
 getData(request, Model.class)
 ...
}
```

BaseHandler.java

```
public abstract class BaseHandler {
 ...
 <
 T > void getData(Request request, Class < ? > clazz) {
   ...
   ?
   ? ? ? ?
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

How to cast request to Model.class from calling method. Now I get `LinkedHashMap`
Help, please. Thank's

Comment: Sorry, My Friend. I couldn't able to understand your program and question. Are those two different classes?

Comment: Yes, they are different classes.

Comment: `
public class RequestHandler extends BaseWebSocketRequestHandler {
 ...
  public void handle(Request request){
  getData(request, Model.class)
 ...
 }
}

public abstract class BaseHandler{
...
 <T> void getData(Request request, Class<?> clazz){
 ...
 ?????
 ...
 }
...
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection you can get a class's constructor and get a new instance.
Doing a new instance on the class is possible, but bad as normally constructors should
be run.

You can also use the class to cast an Object to it, T.

```
//     type parameter
//      |  result: Model                Model.class
//      |  |                             |
public <T> T getData(Request request, Class<T> clazz) {
    Object value = map.get(clazz); // A map of class to class instance.
    if (value != null) {
        return clazz.cast(value);
    }

    T object = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    return object;
}
```